# How do I get x10 mini to show up in adb devices on osx?

Tags: android, debugging, adb, sony, x10

I cant get x10 mini to show up in "adb devices", (only emulators show up). Phone is in usb-debugging-mode, thethering-applications are disabled and on OSX I shouldn't need to download any USB drivers for the phone, so whats wrong here?

/Developer/Utilities/usb probe reports phone as:

```
    Descriptor Version Number:   0x0200
    Device Class:   0   (Composite)
    Device Subclass:   0
    Device Protocol:   0
    Device MaxPacketSize:   64
    Device VendorID/ProductID:   0x0FCE/0x2138   (Sony Ericsson Mobile Communications AB)
    Device Version Number:   0x0224
    Number of Configurations:   1
    Manufacturer String:   1 "SEMC"
    Product String:   2 "SEMC HSUSB Device"
    Serial Number String:   3 "4342xxxx314A5151xxxx"
```

Thankful for any help

Comment: and the 2.1 update (on phone) didn't solve it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the command

```
android update adb
```

This will create a **adb_usb.ini** file in your **$HOME/.android** directory. After you open this file you will see:

```
# ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
# USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE.
```

Just add a new line to file and write **0x0FCE** save that file and exit. Now restart adb server with:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

adb devices now should list your device.

Comment: That solved it, big Thanks! Minor typo though, filename is adb_usb.ini

Answer (score 1):

You write "tethering-applications are disabled.  Are you using EasyTether and did you try the following?:

> ADB on Mac OS X stops recognizing the
>   attached device after installing
>   EasyTether driver. Use
>   kextload/kextunload to unload from
>   memory the EasyTetherUSBEthernet.kext
>   kernel extension manually. It is in
>   /System/Library/Extensions/

Comment: Thanks, problem arose before the easyteather driver for osx even existed. However, this information is essential. You and Ismail will share the bounty points. Thanks.